# Joomla Module not sending email

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email, joomla

I have a small issue I would like some assistance with. I created a simple Joomla module for sending emails. In my testing grounds (localhost and online server), the module works perfectly. After installing it in my clients server, it does not send emails and instead I get this error

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognised expression: unsupported pseudo: email.
```

When I click the send mail button, it works as it should and even alerts you that the mail has been sent succesfully but in actual sense, no email has been sent. I did not change any code, I only zipped, downloaded and installed to my clients site. Both Joomla websites have the same version (3.x). What could be the issue here? you can get to see it on [this link](http://demo.skibzy.com/tnt/) and click on the email button at the bottom centre of the page.

.

Comment: Localhosts don't normally support emails. You may have to add support for it yourself which can sometimes be quite tedious

Comment: I use my gmail credentials in localhost via xampp and works well. The one that ain working is on a live server